# Why are my integers being converted to floats?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently writing an assignment to write a class that creates fractions.  The first few lines of the class are as follows:

```
class Fraction():
    #constructor
    """
    Post-condition:  User calls class with 0, 1, or 2 integers.
    Post-condition:  Fraction object is created.  Numerator and denominator each default
    to 1.

    """
    def __init__(self, numerator = 1, denominator = 1):
        self.__numerator = numerator
        self.__denominator = denominator

    #__str__ method
    """
    Pre-condition:  User has created a fraction object and has call the print function
    to display the fraction value.
    Post-condition: Method checks for a denominator of zero and returns an error message
    if true.  It will then check for float values in the numerator and denominator and 
    convert them to integers if true.  It will then check if the numerator and denominator
    are the same number and return a 1 if true. Next it checks if the denominator can be 
    divided into the numerator with a zero remainder and returns a whole number if true.
    Last, it will return a fraction.

    """
    def __str__(self):
        #check for float in denominator
        if isinstance(self.__denominator, float):
            self.__denominator = int(self.__denominator)
        #check for float in numerator
        if isinstance(self.__numerator, float):
            self.__numerator = int(self.__numerator)
        #check for equality in numerator and denominator
        if self.__numerator == self.__denominator:
            return 1
        #check for zero remainder division 
        elif self.__numerator % self.__denominator == 0:
            wholeNumber = self.__numerator / self.__denominator
            return str(wholeNumber)
        else:
            divisor = self.__numerator
            tmpDenom = self.__denominator
            while tmpDenom:
                divisor, tmpDenom = tmpDenom, divisor % tmpDenom
            self.__numerator = self.__numerator // divisor
            self.__denominator = self.__denominator // divisor
            return str(self.__numerator) + '/' + str(self.__denominator)
```

While running my test in terminal and in IDLE, I'm using the following code just to test my output:

```
from modFraction import Fraction

frac1 = Fraction(15, 16)
print(frac1)
frac2 = Fraction(17, 18)
print(frac2)
print(frac1 + frac2)
```

When I run the output, I end up with the following output:

```
15.0/16.0
17.0/18.0
271.0/144.0
```

Where is my integer input being converted to floats???

Comment: Why do you have so many type checks and conversions in the `__str__` method? That should all happen in `__init__`, not when the thing needs to be printed.

Comment: When I run `print(Fraction(15, 16))`, I get `15/16`. Double check what version of Python you're running, maybe?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error with the code you've shown. (I can see *other* errors, like that one case where you return `1` from `__str__` instead of a string, but not the error you're claiming.)

Comment: @senshin I'm running python 3.2.3

Comment: The same as @user2357112 mentions - I also don't see much benefit in checking something's a float before `int`ing it anyway... If you `int`  an `int` you'll just get the same object back, and if not - you needed to do it anyway.... (so might as well just not type check)

Comment: @Blackwell Sometimes, voodoo occurs if you have old `.pyc` files. Delete all the `.pyc` files in the relevant directories and try again.

Comment: @Blackwell, any reason to reinvent the wheel? http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html

Comment: @juliohm: Because this is an assignment.

Comment: Is IDLE doing something dumb? Have you tried running from the command line to confirm that this is the output?

Comment: @senshin Did that, still getting floats in my fractions.

Comment: @Blackwell One last thing, then - to make sure there isn't something wonky going on with your imports, try putting the calls to `Fraction()` and `print()` in the same file as the definition of the `Fraction` class and running it and seeing if things go wrong.

Comment: @jozzas:  Thank you.  I guess my bad luck is with IDLE...  Doesn't happen in terminal.

Answer (score 3):

I think the solution is that using the built-in "Run Module" in IDLE does some really dumb things to the output sometimes - running in the terminal should give you `int`s as output.

---

Some other tips:

In Python 3, `/` always returns a float. [See PEP 238](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/).

Additionally,  `//` with mixed arguments (float and int) will return a float:

> In particular, if a and b are both ints or longs, the result has
>       the same type and value as for classic division on these types
>       (including the case of mixed input types; **int//long and long//int
>       will both return a long**).

Comment: This is true but not relevant.

Comment: While this is true-ish (`/` doesn't return a float when the arguments are `complex`, or `fractions.Fraction`, or `decimal.Decimal`, etc.), and it may be the cause of the problem, we can't really tell from the code shown.

Comment: I think this is *both* true and relevant.  The OP does `self.__numerator = self.__numerator // divisor`, and if `self.__numerator` is a `float` they will get a `float`.

Comment: @SethMMorton: But `self.__numerator` shouldn't be a float. In fact, `__str__` explicitly makes sure it's not a float, which is kind of weird.

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah, I noticed that after I made the comment.  It's probably the .pyc problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Can't reproduce](http://ideone.com/wjTrH6) with the code you've given.

Note that in Python 3, the regular division operator always returns a float even if both operands are integer. This is changed from Python 2, where the regular division operator will use integer division when both operands are integers. You can force the use integer division by using double slash operator (e.g. `7 // 3 == 2` in both Python 2 and Python 3).

Unrelated hint: the divmod() method is very useful when working with fractions. It gives both the integer division and the remainder at the same time.